# How to allow subprocesses in pytest?

Tags: pytest, fork

When running a test case that calls `os.fork` and then `sys.exit` in the newly created child process, `pytest` will catch the resulting `SystemExit` exception in that new process and mark the relevant test case as failure:

```
>       sys.exit(0)
E       SystemExit: 0
```

Such use may be intentional though. How can it be allowed in a way that does not cause `pytest` to mark it as failure?

Update: An example function that should pass when called from a test case:

```
def example():
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0: # in child
        # Do something and then terminate child.
        sys.exit(0)
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)
    # Parent returns normally without raising any exception.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `os._exit` instead of `sys.exit`. Any other method of terminating the child process results in a second pytest instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools
import os

def allow_fork_exit(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        mainpid = os.getpid()
        try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        except SystemExit as sysexit:
            if sysexit.code or os.getpid() == mainpid:
                raise
            # If pytest sees a SystemExit, it'll mark the test as failure.
            return
    return wrapped
```

Is there a better solution?

In addition to the stackoverflow-mandatory CC BY-SA 4.0 license, you may use this under MIT.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, give it a try

```
def test_fork_fun():
    parent_pid = os.getpid()
    try:
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as e:
            function()
        if os.getpid() == parent_pid:
            assert str(e.value) == "0"
    except BaseException as e:
        if os.getpid() != parent_pid:
            if type(e).__name__ != "Failed":
                raise
        else:
            raise
```

it should fail the test when the exit value is not 0 or there's another exception.

Comment: As far as I understand your variant, it requires the test to `sys.exit`, which is not what I want here. Only the forked process needs to be terminated. The original process hands back control to the test suite by simply returning.

Comment: I was assuming a daemon-like case where the parent forks and exit. If it's not your case, just invert the checks for the pids.

Comment: In that case, we're back to my original solution. I've clarified the question.

Comment: It would help if you provide an example of `function`. Remember you still need to check `OSError` if fork fails, exit values != 0, and other potential exceptions.